# Partial specialization of variadic template member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm struggling with specializations of member functions when they are templated using variadic template.

The following example specializes a whole class and it works fine:

```
template<typename... Args>
class C;

template<class T, typename... Args>
class C<T, Args...> { };

template<>
class C<> { };

int main() {
    C<int, double> c{};
}
```

The following one does not, even though the idea behind it is exactly the same of the one above:

```
class F {
    template<typename... Args>
    void f();
};

template<class T, typename... Args>
void F::f<T, Args...>() { }

int main() {
}
```

I'm getting the following error and I don't understand what it's due to:

```
main.cpp:7:23: error: non-type partial specialization ‘f<T, Args ...>’ is not allowed
 void F::f<T, Args...>() { }
                       ^
main.cpp:7:6: error: prototype for ‘void F::f()’ does not match any in class ‘F’
 void F::f<T, Args...>() { }
      ^
main.cpp:3:10: error: candidate is: template<class ... Args> void F::f()
     void f();
          ^
```

Is there some constraints I'm not aware of when specializing function template?

G++ version is: *g++ (Debian 5.2.1-23) 5.2.1 20151028*

***EDIT***

By the way, the actual problem I'm getting from the real code is:

```
non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘executeCommand<T, Args ...>’ is not allowed
```

Anyway, the reduced example is similar to the real one. I hope the errors are not completely unrelated.

Comment: Function templates can't be partially specialized.

Comment: Do you mean *member function template*?

Comment: @skypjack: member and not member.

Comment: Damn it. Completely forgotten, I'm sorry. The error was clear indeed, but it's ever clear enough when you've understood it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: A good explanation of why not to specialize function templates: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize function templates; only explicit specialization is allowed.

You can get pretty much the same effect using overloading, especially if you use concepts such as [tag dispatching](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

Comment: Good hint. I've already used tag dispatching, but it didn't come to my mind today!! Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken, can you please fix it?

Comment: @tuket link fixed